# How change opacity placeholder in focus input

Tags: css

I need change opacity on input:focus placeholder

Html

```
<input type="text" name="search_cursos" id="search_cursos" placeholder="Procure a vaga que deseja" class="procurarvaga">
```

My scss

```
input.procurarvaga{
        text-align: center;
        &:focus{
            @include placeholder {
                @include opacity(.2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Mixins

```
@mixin opacity($opacity) {
  opacity: $opacity;
  // IE8 filter
  $opacity-ie: ($opacity * 100);
  filter: alpha(opacity=$opacity-ie);
}

@mixin placeholder {
  ::-webkit-input-placeholder {@content}
  :-moz-placeholder           {@content}
  ::-moz-placeholder          {@content}
  :-ms-input-placeholder      {@content}
}
```

My code https://jsfiddle.net/fcothiagofreitas/ubxzswkw/

Here with css work http://jsfiddle.net/XDutj/27/

Comment: Instead of `color:red`, use `rgba(240, 0, 0 , 0.4)` for `input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder`

Comment: in css my code work, i need code work with sass